# apply resulting in list instead of dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, missing-data

I have a dataframe with cases that repeat on the rows.  Some rows have more complete data than others.  I would like to group cases and then assign the first non-missing value to all NA cells in that column for that group.  This seems like a simple enough task but I'm stuck. I have working syntax but when I try to use apply to apply the code to all columns in the dataframe I get a list back instead of a dataframe.  Using do.call(rbind) or rbindlist or unlist doesn't quite fix things either.

Here's the syntax.

```
df$groupid<-group_indices (df,id1,id2) #creates group id on the basis of a combination of two variables

df%<>%group_by(id1,id2) #actually groups the dataframe according to these variables

df<-summarise(df, xvar1=xvar1[which(!is.na(xvar1))[1]]) #this code works great to assign the first non missing value to all missing values but it only works on 1 column at a time (X1).
```

I have many columns so I try using apply to make this a manageable task..

```
df<-apply(df, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) {summarise(df, x=x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])
  }
)
```

This gets me a list for each variable, I wanted a dataframe (which I would then de-duplicate).  I tried rbindlist and do.call(rbind) and these result in a long dataframe with only 3 columns - the two group_by variables and 'x'.

I know the problem is simply how I'm using apply, probably the indexing with 'which', but I'm stumped.

Comment: *"assign the first non-missing value to all NA cells"* sounds a lot like *"replacing each 'NA' with the most recent non-'NA' prior to it"* from `zoo::na.locf`. I find it a lot safer (in concept at least) vice assuming the first value is always the best to use. Are you certain that the "best choice" is always the first and not the most-recent non-`NA` value?

Comment: They're all date and time stamped the exact same, none are 'newer' per se but I appreciate your point. These data are calls for service and while multiple units can respond to a call, not all end up with complete data.  I'm going to de-dup the file but would like to retain as much information as possible before doing so.  I am going to look at the zoo package though!

Answer (score 0):

What about using `lapply` with `do.call` and `cbind`, like the following:

```
df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(x) {summarise(df, x=x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])}))
```

Comment: An interesting approach but it doesn't quite seem to work.  The columns seem to come out labeled as x1,x2,xn where n is the number of columns in the original file.  The grouping variables id1 and id2 also repeat n times.  It's so close and could probably be cleaned up to work but I just don't know how.

Comment: I tried using "paste0 in there with the summarise command to get the name of the variable to match (as it is, it's just 'x') but this does not work.  I've run into this issue before and the core problem is that I've not found a good way to reference the 'name' of the vector rather than the 'contents' of the vector.  I feel like paste has worked on previous problems but it does not seem to work here